# ASP display code between two date/times

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to have a page that has a button appear only between two dates and times. I used the following code and the button appeared at the correct time (12:01am on 5/15/2017), but then disappeared before the 11:59pm 5/19/2017 when it should have (I believe it disappeared around 9:30 to 10am on 5/15/2017). I'm not sure why, I am guessing there is something incorrect with the date comparison portion of the code that is interpreting the time as 1000... else why did it work at all?

```
<%
ctime = FormatDateTime(Now)
if ctime => "5/15/2017 12:01 AM" and ctime <= "5/19/2017 11:59 PM" then %>
    Button HTML code
<% end if %>
```

Would the code below be the correct code to use?

```
If (Now >= #5/15/2017 12:01 am#) And (Now <= #5/19/2017 11:59 pm#) then %>
    Button HTML code
<% end if %>
```

Comment: `FormatDateTime()` returns a string not a datetime value.

Comment: `If Now >= CDate("5/15/2017 12:01 am") And Now <= CDate("5/19/2017 11:59 pm") Then`